# Find $v(t)$ from force differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I need to find $v(t)$ and then $x(t)$ given 
$$
\dfrac{dp}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{ mv}{\sqrt(1-v^2/c^2)}=F.  
$$
I've tried just integrating both sides with respect to $t$, but the $v$ in the numerator and denominator makes the algebra very hard.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: $F$ is a constant ?

Comment: Servabat--no, F depends on both velocity and time.  It's actually just "F" in the final solution.

Comment: Then $v$ as to be expressed as a function of what variables ?

Comment: v is supposed to be a function of t

Comment: There are no $t$ in the expression you gave. Appart if $F$ is a constant, no $t$ will appear (and It's not so no $t$ will appear). The informations you gave are unsuffiscient to give an expression as a function of t.

Comment: servabat--Ok maybe F is a constant then.  That is everything the problem gives. The expression for x has t's in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to solve for the velocity as a function of time since it's not part of the expression for force. However if you would like to solve for it in terms of p (which may be sort of circular):
If you cancel the $dt$ bounds, you obtain
$$dp={d}{{mv}\over{\sqrt{1-{v^2\over{c^2}}}}}$$
Since velocity is likely the variable of the right side, you can move the $dv$ over and give the radical a common denominator, then moving it to the top. This gives you
$$dp={mc\over{\sqrt{c^2-v^2}}}{dv}$$
From there you can integrate using trigonometric substitution and get what the momentum equals in terms of the velocity. Hopefully you can then manipulate that to find the velocity is in terms of momentum.
Not sure if this helped at all since you wanted an answer in terms of time but that's all I could offer.